# Is it possible to use an IF statement inside COALESCE SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a coalesce statement that I am using for pagination. However I would like to use an IF statement inside of it like so:

```
OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * COALESCE(@RowsPerPage, IF(@TotalNumberOfRows > 1000, 1000, @TotalNumberOfRows), 0) ROWS
```

So if the amount of `@RowsPerPage` hasn't been set, then it uses the `@TotalNumberOfRows` that the query returned. However, if the `@TotalNumberOfRows` is over 1000, I would like it to use 1000.

The error I am getting is:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

Comment: Use `CASE`in SQL Server

Comment: [`IF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a logical flow operation, not a function. You appear to want [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), not `IF`, which is a short hand `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * COALESCE(@RowsPerPage,IIF(@TotalNumberOfRows > 1000, 1000, @TotalNumberOfRows),0) ROWS
```

or

```
OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * COALESCE(@RowsPerPage,CASE WHEN @TotalNumberOfRows > 1000 THEN 1000 ELSE @TotalNumberOfRows END,0) ROWS
```